# How to make Terraform archive_file resource pick up changes to source files?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

Using TF 0.7.2 on a Win 10 machine.

I'm trying to set up an edit/upload cycle for development of my lambda functions in AWS, using the new "archive_file" resource introduced in TF 0.7.1

My configuration looks like this:

```
resource "archive_file" "cloudwatch-sumo-lambda-archive" {
  source_file = "${var.lambda_src_dir}/cloudwatch/cloudwatchSumologic.js"
  output_path = "${var.lambda_gen_dir}/cloudwatchSumologic.zip"
  type = "zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "cloudwatch-sumo-lambda" {
  function_name = "cloudwatch-sumo-lambda"
  description = "managed by source project"
  filename = "${archive_file.cloudwatch-sumo-lambda-archive.output_path}"
  source_code_hash = "${archive_file.cloudwatch-sumo-lambda-archive.output_sha}"
  handler = "cloudwatchSumologic.handler"

  ...
}
```

This works the first time I run it - TF creates the lambda zip file, uploads it and creates the lambda in AWS.
The problem comes with updating the lambda.

If I edit the cloudwatchSumologic.js file in the above example, TF doesn't appear to know that the source file has changed - it doesn't add the new file to the zip and doesn't upload the new lambda code to AWS.

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration, or is the archive_file resource not meant to be used in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could be seeing a bug.  I'm on 0.7.7 and the issue now is the SHA changes even when you don't make changes.  Hashicorp will be updating this resource to a data source in 0.7.8

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/8492

Comment: Yeh - I tried posting about it on the mailing list, but no response.  There's other probems with it anyway; especially around x-platform creation of the archive, zip ordering, path separators, etc.  I'm thinking TF is not the right solution for complex lambda infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the base64 hash like this:

```
source_code_hash = "${archive_file.cloudwatch-sumo-lambda-archive.output_base64sha256}"
```